# For "Auto-Renewable Subscription", if I want to have more than one subscription in my product, how can I set things up?

Tags: ios

Say I am developing a game.

I want to offer two different subscription memberships.

$5 monthly, *VIP Basic*: Can get 100 gems per day.
$9 monthly, *VIP Advanced*: Can get 300 gems per day.

Can I set up two subscription memberships?

What if the user purchase *VIP Basic* for 3 days and want to upgrade to *VIP Advanced*, does he/she have an option to upgrade or he/she has to wait for the first subscription to expire?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple subscription options and your users can change their subscription preferences whenever they'd like. Although there are many different tutorials on the internet some things are recommended by almost everyone:

- First things first you'll need to verify the subscriptions of your users by sending a receipt data to Apple's iTunes servers. Do **NOT** do it on the phone or locally. Do it on a web server of your own, preferably having HTTPS certificate.
- Remember to store a user's subscription either locally or on a web server since Apple Review documents requires your users to have the edit option available to them in your app.
- Users should have the restore option available to them as well. So don't forget to add that to your subscription integration.
- When displaying your subscription prices and details do it by fetching their info from Apple. Don't add static texts or prices since review team will reject your app because of this.
- Subscription prices can be changed for each country from Appstore Connect panel. Remember to adjust the prices based on certain countries economic state.
- You can't test real subscription options on development environment thus you'll need to use some sandbox environment parameters. Don't forget to remove them when you are sending an update.

Lastly here is a [good tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1458378-in-app-purchase-tutorial-auto-renewable-subscriptions) with example codes on how to add auto-renewable subscriptions to an app.

Comment: Thanks for the information but it seems not to be an answer to my question. I want to know when a user switches from preference A to preference B, can he/she just pay the price difference?

Comment: Yes they can and they must. This is handled in Apple's side for purchasing the product.